# LED works but speaker does not work in multivibration circuit

Tags: speakers, multisim, oscillation

1. This circuit oscillates with LED (in multisim 14).
   [image]
2. This circuit does not oscillate with speaker (labview, in real breadboard it only beeps twice and becomes silent, playback time 10 s, sample frequence 220 Hz), then changed on R1 from 47k to 10000k and C1 from 1 nF  to 100 uF, it does not oscillate at all with all attempts. Any suggestion on changing some parameter to make this work?
   [image]

Comment: I heard that everyone hates this circuit because making it oscillate is so unpredictable :)

Comment: It looks like the load impedance has an impact. So, use the same oscillator you used with the LED but replace the LED with speaker. Then try and play with speaker impedance until it oscillates.

Comment: Also consider, what is different between the LED impedance and the speaker impedance?

Comment: Q2 is overloaded by the speaker's very low impedance. You have only "luck' preventing the LED from being burned out since it is missing a series current-limiting resistor. Add an emitter-follower transistor to drive the speaker.

Comment: @Audioguru Wouldn't an emitter follower still leave a problem? While a resistor tolerates a constant DC current **bias** in it without a care, a speaker not so much. The current itself may drive the voice coil to its limits. Also, there is a LOT of feedback from a speaker. I suspect it would be better to look elsewhere than an emitter follower to drive a speaker. Or are you thinking of passively sinking into an 8 Ohm R, with a capacitor to a speaker?

Comment: @Audioguru, for LED, in real breadboard of course I will add series resistor. I just want to create an oscillation with this circuit or similar circuit.

Comment: With your 3.5V battery, the base of Q2 has a current of only 8mA. Then the collector current of Q2 will be only 80mA to 160mA which will barely drive an 8 ohms speaker but will make the LED very bright. There will be no feedback unless the capacitor is a microphonic ceramic one. A speaker should never have a DC voltage in it.

Comment: hi @Audioguru, I am referring to the oscillation wave, even it can not drive it to sound but why isn't there oscillation?  if I replace one far below 8ohm then it would work?  what is the ohm for labview speaker in multisim i can not see this.

Comment: An 8 ohm speaker needs a high current that the output transistor cannot provide. 8 ohms is almost a dead short.

Comment: @Audioguru, share more background, this circuit with 8ohm speaker works and speaker voices out. but in simulation in MULTISIM it does not work out with LABVIEW speaker. I see no change on oscillator. so is there any way to work this out?

Comment: sorry, Type error,  This circuit does not oscillate with speaker (labview, in real breadboard it only beeps twice and becomes silent,   it shall be in simulation, in realboard it oscillates.

Answer (score 2):

As @user253751 pointed out, this circuit is "unpredictable".

For one configuration,

[image]

[image]

And another,

[image]

[image]

Comment: I take a close look and found nothing different among these circuits, why waves vary?  also I have only labview speaker in multisim, so it is hard to copy your speaker model.

Comment: it looks like it works with your speaker 12s330 in simulation. it also works for 8ohm in real breadboard. so how to drive LABVIEW speaker work or to see oscillation with this particular speaker. My textbook has many this circuit with speaker looped so I have to work this out. any way to change speaker impedance in MULTISIM. can you try this circuit with this speaker and see how it does not kick it out of the stuck voltage state.  LED works fine for me in breadboard and in simulation.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone. with some advice from NI communities it was modified to work successfully.

it looks like impedance issue with labview speaker. since it works in breadboard with my 8ohm speaker, so I simulated it by replacing labview speaker with an 8ohm resistance to have it oscillate and then wired labview speaker to in between Q2 collector and this added resistance in parallel (also oscilliscope shows oscillation). it worked on this labview speaker during playback with sound.
btw. higher resistance value would make is silent.